# Merge [grapheme-cluster] into [grapheme]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

There is a little-used tag [grapheme-cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grapheme-cluster) which seems (to me) synonymous with [grapheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grapheme). I propose that the former be made synonymous with the latter; not because they are actually synonymous, but because questions about one are likely to overlap with questions about the other.

I also propose that `extended-grapheme-cluster` also be made a synonym, pre-emptively.

Also, I feel like this tag should have a plural name, `graphemes`, and not `grapheme`, to reflect its typical English usage.

Comment: The two tags don't mean the same thing.  Read the Tag Excerpt; someone actually took the trouble to explain what the grapheme tag means.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it doesn't provide any explanation for why "grapheme" should be different from "grapheme cluster" for tagging purposes (even if they are technically different things).

Comment: I don't see anything in that tag excerpt to lead me or the author to believe there's any correspondence at all between the two tags. That they both contain the word "grapheme" is not sufficient correlation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the questions are all centering around the same topic ("grapheme" is a linguistics concept, "grapheme cluster" is the Unicode equivalent thereof), and without usage guidance for _both_ tags to disambiguate them I can't see anything but confusion resulting from the existence of both tags. I don't see much benefit to distinguishing graphemes-as-encoded-in-Unicode from graphemes-in-general, especially since we already have [tag:unicode].

Comment: Perhaps the Tag Excerpts could benefit from some clarification, then.